# jQuery - Why the callback function has delay?

Tags: jquery

I hope to loop & show 3 images

when show the last image ,it need much times to callback again the runIt() function.

Can I set it to no delay then callback again the function??

```
function runIt() {      
    $("#image1,#image2,#image3").hide();
        $("#image1").show(0);
        $("#image2").delay(1000).show(0);
        $("#image3").delay(2000).show(0,0,runIt);
        }
runIt();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your title and questions asked seemed conflicting to me, anyway you can use `setTimeout`

```
function runIt() {      
    $("#image1,#image2,#image3").hide();
        $("#image1").show(0);
        $("#image2").delay(1000).show(0);
        $("#image3").delay(2000).show(0,0,function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){   
                          runIt();                     
                      }, 2000 );

               });
        }
runIt();
```

[**DMEO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8NNm/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the function every **x** seconds? Then use setInterval()

```
setInterval(runIt, 1000); // 1000 = 1 second
```

so your code would look like this:

```
function runIt() {      
    $("#image1,#image2,#image3").hide();
    $("#image1").show(0);
    $("#image2").delay(1000).show(0);
    $("#image3").delay(2000).show(0);
}
setInterval(runIt, 3000);
```